# Invitation to anti-plagiarism service Turnitin

Tags: plagiarism

I received the following unsolicited email:

> Subject: A new account Turnitin has been created for you
> Hi NAME SURNAME,
> you have been added as a teacher to the account, xxx, by Turnitin xxx Administrator.
> as a new teacher, you are joining a global community of training experts. We are pleased to have you with us.
> Are you ready to configure your classes?

With a button  lending to a Turnitin signup page, whose address is similar to:

https://www.turnitin.com/password_reset1.asp?utm_source=getting-started-instructor&utm_medium=webpage&utm_campaign=onboarding

However, isn't Turnitin a paid service?
Have you perhaps received this invitation and, if you registered, how you use it?

Comment: This looks like spam to me. Are you teaching at an institution that could have automatically signed you up? If not, just delete it.

Comment: @astronat: When my institution does so, they send us an internal email first. 
What I don't understand is why the link button points to https://www.turnitin.com. 
If it is a spam, then it comes straight from Turnitin, which should be a respectable company.

Comment: @antonio: *What I don't understand is why the link button points to turnitin.com* – Are you sure about that?

Comment: That being said, I do not see much we can answer better than you can. We cannot tell you whether the mail is legit, and if it is, [we do not really like to evaluate their services](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4062/7734).

Answer (score 1):

> by Turnitin xxx Administrator.

Ask xxx if they created an account for you. If they have no idea what you are talking about, or xxx is not in your organisation, mark as spam and move on. That Turnitin is a paid service matters little, as many universities pay for it on organisational level.

Comment: It happens that I have received the email informing about the activation of the service in my university. So, sorry for the inconvenience. Probably, I should remove the post, do I?

Comment: @antonio you could turn your comment into an answer and mark it as accepted. This way, if anyone runs into the same issu and looks it up here, they can find an aanswer that works.